# Can you add additional String/Integer variables to android XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

With a simple bit of Android XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >
</EditText>
```

Is there any way that you can add an additional String or Integer variable to the edit text field, such as an Integer called Section ID which can be set and called in the Java code. I am not talking about changing the "@+id" variable as there may be multiple Views with this variable. If so how could this be created/edited/called from within the java code itself.

Comment: You can always create your own edittext class and add your personal parameters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setTag()` and `getTag()` for this purpose